# Learning Nodejs & ES6 stuck at some point

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

following is a ES6 method.call() method which gives me error

```
 var obj = {
            name: "Hello ES6 call",
            greet: function(somedata) {
                this.somedata = somedata
                console.log(this.somedata)  //somedata works
                console.log(somedata) //somedata works
                console.log(`Hello ${ this.somedata } `) 

//Error this.somedata undefined
        }
    }

    obj.greet.call({name:"from call"},"somedata");
```

this.somedata undefined using ES6 Template literals

```
//second question
var Emitter = require("events");
var util = require("util");

function Greetr() {
    this.greeting = "greetr function ";
    this.greet = function(data) {
        console.log(this.greeting, data)
        this.emit('greet', data);
    }
}

util.inherits(Greetr, Emitter);
var greeter1 = new Greetr();

greeter1.on('greet', function(data) {
    console.log("greet on", data);
});

greeter1.greet(" some data"); //works
greeter1.greet.call({greeting:"greeting call function"}, "call data")
```

this.emit is undefined why is there any way out using call() function

Comment: in first question have problem with "template string" where "this.somedata" is undefined

Comment: in second question "this.emit" is undefined if i use greeter1.greet.call({greeting:"greeting call function"}, "call data")

Comment: Only ask one question per question. The first example doesn't throw the error you claim it does. It works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

When you call `greeter1.greet.call({greeting:"greeting call function"}, "call data")`, you're explicitly telling it to use `{greeting: "greeting call function"}` as `this`. So when it calls this.emit, it's undefined, because you've told it to be undefined.

I recommend against using this sort of strategy where you're explicitly defining `this`, but if it's really what you want to do, then you'll have to add an emit function into the object you're passing in. I take it you want greeter1 to be the thing doing the emitting, even though you've passing in a different object? If that's the case, then you'll probably need to do this:

```
greeter1.greet.call({
    greeting:"greeting call function",
    emit: greeter1.emit.bind(greeter1)
}, "call data");
```

Again, i recommend against doing this. I think it would be much better to make greet accept the greeting as a function parameter (perhaps with a default value), and not rely on hijacking `this`

```
var Emitter = require("events");
var util = require("util");

function Greetr() {
    this.greet = function(data, greeting = "greetr function") {
        console.log(greeting, data)
        this.emit('greet', data);
    }
}

util.inherits(Greetr, Emitter);
var greeter1 = new Greetr();

greeter1.on('greet', function(data) {
    console.log("greet on", data);
});

greeter1.greet(" some data");
greeter1.greet("call data", "greeting call function");
```